# EXT JS 64 bit Internet Explorer rendering issue?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs, rendering

I seem to be having an issue with displaying charts in 64 bit internet explorer on windows 7. I have attached two screenshots 1) 32 bit mode 2) 64 bit mode. Has anyone else seen this? or have an idea as to why it may be doing this?

[image: 32 bit Mode]
[image: 64 bit Mode]

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer's 64-bit implementation of VML is poor, to say the least. It does support SVG in standards mode, however.

I just finished a large project involving charts and I ran into the exact same problem you did. Text boxes cutting off, label alignment and rotation issues, the whole works. The only solution I'm aware of is to use 32-bit IE and hold out for IE10. Sorry.